# Iterating through multiple objects with same property within one array

Tags: jquery

I am trying to iterate through all the objects in this array and show all of the captions. Eventually I want to show everything, but right now I would settle for just this one thing. How do I display all of the captions on the screen?

```
var thumbnails = [
    {
        caption: 'An Avocado',
        image: 'images/avocado.jpg',
        url: 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avocado'
    },
    {
        caption: 'A Cat',
        image: 'images/cat.jpg',
        url: 'http://mashable.com/category/cats/'
    },
    {
        caption: 'A Dog',
        image: 'images/dog.jpg',
        url: 'https://www.petfinder.com/dog-breeds/'
    },
    {
        caption: 'A Llama',
        image: 'images/llama.jpg',
        url: 'http://animals.nationalgeographic.com/animals/mammals/llama/'
    },
    {
        caption: 'Pandas are the best',
        image: 'images/panda.jpg',
        url: 'http://pandas.pydata.org/'
    },
    {
        caption: 'This is random',
        image: 'images/thumb.jpg',
        url: 'http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/thumb'
    }
];
```

This is what I have, but it only displays the last caption.

```
$.each(thumbnails, function(index, value) {
    var myCaption = value.caption;
    $('.thumbnails').html(myCaption);
    console.log(myCaption);
});
```

Comment: Because you're overwriting the previous value with `.html(myCaption)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call append() instead of html().
The way it works now is your previous values are being stomped and only the last is shown.

https://jsbin.com/makecekuqa/edit?html,js,console,output

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your code to following

```
var myCaption = "";
$.each(thumbnails, function(index, value) {
    myCaption += value.caption + " ";

});
$('.thumbnails').html(myCaption);
console.log(myCaption);
```